# LUIS to MySQL query - Azure Chatbot

Tags: mysql, database, azure, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

How to generate MySQL Querys with LUIS and fetch data from the DB hosted in Azure?

Should generate a natural language query to an MySQL Query.
e.g.

How much beer was drunken on the oktoberfest 2018? 
--> GET amountOfBeer FROM Oktoberfest WHERE Year ==2018;

Does anyone has an idea how to get this to work?

Already generated small Intents in LUIS e.g. GetAmountOfBeer

Dont know how to generate the MySQL Statements and how to get the data from the DB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this, or something similar, using intents and entities. How successful this can be depends on how many and how diverse your queries need to be. First lets start with the phrase you mentioned: "How much beer was drunken on the oktoberfest 2018". You can easily (as you've done) add this as an utterance for an intent, `GetAmountOfBeer`. Though I'm a fan of intent names that you can read as "I want to `GetAmountOfBeer`", here you may want to name the intent `amountOfBeer` so you can use it in your query directly.

Next you need to set up you entities. For year (or datetime rather) that should be easy, as I believe there are some predefined entities for this. I think you need to use a datetime recognizer to parse out the right attribute (like year), but I haven't tried to do this before. Next, Oktoberfest seems to be a specific holiday or event in your DB, so you could create a list entity of all the events you have.

What you are left with is something like (pseudocode) GET `topIntent` FROM `eventEntity` WHERE Year ==`datetime.Year`, or something like that.

If your query set is more complex, you might have to have multiple GET statements, but you could put those in a switch statement by topIntent so that, no matter what the intent is, you can parse out the correct values. You also might want to build this into a dialog where you can check if the entities exist, and if not, you can prompt the user for the missing data.